# Hibernate update not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new with hibernate and I was trying to update a mapped object with the following code, but it does not update

```
factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
session = factory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
String hql = "UPDATE  "+tableName+" SET  "+columnName+" =  '"+columnValue+"' WHERE  id ="+id+";";
Query query=session.createSQLQuery(hql);
t.commit();
```

Am I missing something? It do not crash nor update the record.

NOTE: I am using Hibernate3 and Mysql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing `query.executeUpdate()`;

Also, if you're updating a mapped object I would recommend you to make the changes to the java object, and let Hibernate do the update for you. Or at least use a hql query, not a native one.

Make sure that your persistence.xml file has show_sql set to true and watch the log to see if the update is executed.

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

Comment: query.execute() gives me an error on Eclipse, I can only use query.executeUpdate(), but it does not work

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `query.executeUpdate()` to run the query.

Also it is suggested that you use `parameters` instead of inline arguments. For eg. if the `columnName = O'Reilly` then the whole query will go wrong.
Also if it is a mapped object you can use HQL rather than SQL query

Instead you can use this

```
//entity is your hibernate entity obj
String hql = "UPDATE  " + entity.getClass().getName + " as entity SET entity." + fieldName  + "= :columnValue WHERE  entity = :entity";
Query query=session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("columnValue", columnValue).setParameter("entity", entity);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Notice that you don't need to use single quotes. `setParameter` handles it.

Comment: if it's a hql query instead of columnName he should use the name of the field that is mapped to that column. also, .setParameter("entity", entity) should be replaced with .setParameter("entity", id);

Comment: @tibtof Thanks for the `columnName` clarification, and you can use entity as is. It is mandatory for each hibernate mapping to give an id field in the mapping. This will be resolved at the run time.